# How to post data using Ajax jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send data from my website to a server for login form. I have a PHP script for that and it works fine as I already made an Android application using the same script. I am new to web development so I got stuck here.

I am getting an error of invalid keys but I mention proper key values in the name attribute. And after success I want to capture those values and as it contains some user information and I want to display it later.

**HTML code**

```
<form id="loginform">
  <label for="phonenumber">Mobile Number</label>
  <br/>
  <!--<input type="tel" name="telNo" type="tel" size="20"  maxlength="13">-->
  <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid" size="20" maxlength="13" class="numeric" /><br>

  <span class="error" style="color: red; display: none">Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    $(function() {
      $(".numeric").bind("keypress", function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
        $(".error").css("display", ret ? "none" : "inline");
        return ret;
      });
      $(".numeric").bind("paste", function(e) {
        return false;
      });
      $(".numeric").bind("drop", function(e) {
        return false;
      });
    });

  </script>
  <br/>
  <label for="Name">Password</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="password" id="upassword" name="upassword">
  <br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Login">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#loginform');

    frm.submit(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: post,
        url: "https://smilestechno.000webhostapp.com/ChkRMNRegistered.php",
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('Submission was successful.');
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log('An error occurred.');
          console.log(data);
        },
      });
    });

  </script>
</form>
```

*Error*

> Notice: Undefined index: userid in /storage/ssd1/323/4193323/public_html/ChkRMNRegistered.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: upassword in /storage/ssd1/323/4193323/public_html/ChkRMNRegistered.php on line 7
> `{"result":[{"ResultStatus":"FAIL"},{"PPLink":"http://smilestechno.000webhostapp.com/ImagesUpload/abc.jpg"}]}`

Comment: Please use proper indentation. This would make it easier to follow your code and the closing `</form>` wouldn't be missing.

Comment: Like [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+post+data+using+Ajax+jquery%3F&oq=How+to+post+data+using+Ajax+jquesry%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.567j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: yes i closed form tag also @Andreas

Comment: Sholdn't it be `type: "POST"` instead of `type: post` ?

Comment: can you show the php script what there on line 6 / 7?